# Protect the content of a static library in C

Tags: c

I have created a static library (.lib). The source code looks like this:

Source file:

```
void foo(void)
{
  MyType var;
  var.val1 = 40;
  var.val2 = 30;
  use(var);
}
```

Header filer (libheader.h):

```
/* Exported API */
void foo(void);
```

Main project:

```
#include "libheader.h" // XX.lib already imported to the main project

int main()
{
  // some code
  foo(); // Breakpoint here and step in
  // some code
  return 0;
}
```

In the main project, I imported the library and included "libheader.h" and I called `foo()`. When I debug my code and I put a breakpoint on `foo()`then I click on 'Step in' the assembler code of the static library is shown in the debug console and I can see local variables content like `var` (in the example). I can even see in the call stack that `use(var)` has been called.

My question is: This library should be protected before being delivered to the client. Is it normal that the content (variables, function names, calls ...) of a .lib file can be seen during debug? Is there a way to crypt/protect it?

Comment: First of all build a *release* version of the library, where all debug symbols are stripped. Secondly, if you only distribute the binary library file (and the header file) there's no source available for the user of the library and all the user can see is the generated assembly code. And it's impossible to "hide" the assembly code.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The problem is not in the assembler code. I tried to use the library in a new project. The call stack shows functions inside the lib and its local variables with their value.

Comment: Sounds like you have compiled with debug set on, which compiler are you using?

Comment: @KrzysztofSzewczyk: The question asks about variable names, which can be omitted from the built library, and internal function names can also be omitted. Your statement “You can’t protect anything” is false.

Comment: You *did* build (and use) a *release* version of the library? Without any debug information (like variable or function names)? Perhaps you need to add an extra build-step for the release build to `strip` such information (depends on the environment and compilers)?

Comment: @EricPostpischil not only - quoting op - "variables, function names, calls"

Comment: It works. Thank you. As mentioned: The solution is to compile a release version of the library.

Comment: @KrzysztofSzewczyk: Yes, you could have written that external function names cannot be omitted. But that is not what you wrote. Your statement “You can’t protect anything” was false.

Comment: Experienced and motivated revengineer will turn the binary to maintainable and readable codebase. You can't protect the codebase.

Comment: @KrzysztofSzewczyk When it comes to exchanges between partners, how one part could protect his own source code if it could be reversed ? Is there another solution beside using a static library ?

Comment: You're boiling it down to XY problem, the solution is somewhere else.